# VSCode search/go to definitions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I searched in vscode site but I couldn't find information on the following:

Is there any way to search definition in other files.

For example: 
In sublime text I can open command pallette (ctrl+p) and write 'User.php@delete' - this will find the method and if i click enter I will go the the specific file and in the line where method 'delete' is.

Does the functionality exist in VSCode (or with extension).

Thanks

Comment: You can use a shortcut : `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`O`

Answer (score 20):

There are multiple options to search function/definition.

According to your convenience, you can choose one of the below options :

1. Best shortcut: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`O` and type your function name.
2. Press `Ctrl+P` for "quick open", then you can use @ or @: The latter is handy to see all the symbols in the file grouped by classes, constants, fields, methods
3. Press `Ctrl+T` to searches across files, not just the current file.

Comment: This should be the answer. Especially useful `Ctrl+T`

Answer (score 1):

Hover the method and press crtl. The method will be underlined and show a tooltip with definition. Mouse left click = go to definition.

Answer (score 0):

yes, in command palete enter @ symbol (without preceding >) end method name.

Comment: This shows method in the current file. I want when I am in index.php for example to go directly to User.php@delete.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Ctrl + P then start with #.